# merge CAF (core audio format,Linear PCM) file into a video(mjpeg) file using ffmpeg (programatically)

Tags: ffmpeg, caf

As the title said, I have a CAF file and I want to insert that file into a video file using ffmpeg(Programmatically ) using C.

CAF file has Linear PCM audio format

I am successfully able to build the video file and now want to add the audio to the video file from CAF (Core Audio Format) file.

Can anyone provide a sample please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

FFMpeg does not has encoders for CAF file.

To add the audio to video, your core audio format in linear PCM encoding can be treated as a wav file!

In other words, CAF file + Linear PCM encoding can be treated as raw audio file and can be renamed as wav file. Now you feed this raw file as input to ffmpeg along with the video file.

Keep a watch on FFMpeg updates, in future they may support CAF file. In that case we can feed in the raw CAF file to FFMpeg.

Comment: Actually ffmpeg is accepting the CAF file with out any problem :)

Comment: Then what is the problem? You can just send two files, video without audio & the audio file as input to ffmpeg's main function with -i option and provide a output file name to ffmpeg's main with -o option. FFMpeg will create the output file which has merged video and audio data.